# import sbt project to intellij result akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I am trying to import existing sbt project to intellij 
I am getting this error :

```
akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [simple-service-actor] is not unique!
    at akka.actor.dungeon.ChildrenContainer$NormalChildrenContainer.reserve(ChildrenContainer.scala:130)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.reserveChild(Children.scala:77)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.reserveChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:202)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:552)
    at spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp$class.startServer(SimpleRoutingApp.scala:52)
    at com.lihaoyi.workbench.Plugin$.startServer(Plugin.scala:16)
    at com.lihaoyi.workbench.Plugin$$anonfun$6.apply(Plugin.scala:97)
    at com.lihaoyi.workbench.Plugin$$anonfun$6.apply(Plugin.scala:97)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:134)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:66)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:75)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [simple-service-actor] is not unique!
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

However the project compiles and run when using sbt command line